# Resize LaTeX Histogram

Tags: pgfplots, plot, histogram

I wrote this LaTeX code for generating a histogram. The problem that arises is that the histogram bars overlap and do not appear well defined as there are many coordinates in the graph, namely 1740. Is there a way to resize the graph so that it looks as clean as possible? Below is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar interval,
    xlabel={Feature},
    ylabel={Value},
    ymin=0,
    ymax=1,
    xtick=\empty,
    xticklabels=\empty,
    ytick=\empty,
    yticklabels=\empty,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
    anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
]
\addplot[ybar,fill=yellow] coordinates {(1,0.5673234066308034) (2,0.2610627037789374) (3,0.19810336628001157) (4,0.17819359523137376) (5,0.17591815359754182) (6,0.174282741730368) %other coordinate
(435,0.0701053325628252) };
\addplot[ybar,fill=gray] coordinates {(436,0.07006473264772355) (437,0.07001409888465146) (438,0.06996899553023585) 
%other coordinate
 (1740,0.02100317004724812) };
\legend{Selezionate, Non Selezionate}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX StackExchange! Could you please edit your question to clarify your goal? You say you want a histogram—do the coordinates represent probabilities? (They don't add up to one.) If so, you may want to see the [PGFPlots histogram documentation](https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/libs-statistics#sec-51.2).

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you have a problem to visualize too densely data. Here's my analysis:

- switching from `ybar`s to `ycomb`s (thin bars so to say) didn't change the visual overlap
- you simply can't tell about 2000 data distributed over, say, 20 cm = 200 mm, so 1 data 'bar' would be 0.2 mm wide (roughly) = 200 nm, which is in the range of UltraViolet wave lengths for reference
- it also won't help to switch to a line or scatter plot for the same reason of limited resolution

To verify, and to show, your data are fine enough in principle I put them on a logarithmic x-scale:

[image: semilog]

Modified code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=newest}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{semilogxaxis}[
    title={Demonstrating the visual problem: too many data},
    %    ybar interval,
    %    xlabel={Feature},
    %    ylabel={Value},
    %    ymin=0,
    %    ymax=1,
    %    xtick=\empty,
    %    xticklabels=\empty,
    %    ytick=\empty,
    %    yticklabels=\empty,
    %    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
    %    anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ycomb,
    ]
    \addplot[red] coordinates {(1,0.5673234066308034) (2,0.2610627037789374) (3,0.19810336628001157) (4,0.17819359523137376) (5,0.17591815359754182) (6,0.174282741730368) %other coordinate
    (435,0.0701053325628252) };
    \addplot[gray] coordinates {(436,0.07006473264772355) (437,0.07001409888465146) (438,0.06996899553023585) 
    %other coordinate
     (1740,0.02100317004724812) };
    \legend{Selezionate, Non Selezionate}
    \end{semilogxaxis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

So, if this problem is still relevant, I suggest to change the way of visualization. A few scenarios for different solutions:

- split and copy: instead of 1 big (wide) graph, have several, representing, say 200 data points each (i.e. 9 diagrams)
- do a little less: summarize into classes; use histograms, boxplots or violin plots (there's a new package for the latter) to characterize each class
- rusching through: provide 2 distributions, one for Selezionate, one for Non Sel.
- inversion (kind of): IF the sequenz number has NO meaning, find a different way to look at, perceive and visualize your data; i.e. what is this diagram really trying to say? what's it's one and only key message?